# Error using Ajax.BeginForm when giving a callback parameter for OnSuccess, OnFailure, OnComplete and OnBegin

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to use an Ajax form, and whenever I provide a callback method to any of the AjaxOptions properties I get this error..

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method

If I do not provide a callback function to any of the properties (OnSuccess, OnFailure, OnComplete, or OnBegin) no error occurs and the form gets posted correctly.

Here is my code.

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("someAction", "SomeController", new AjaxOptions() {
        HttpMethod="POST",
        UpdateTargetId = "feedbackMsg",
        OnSuccess = "ShowConfirmationMessage"
    }))
{ %>
```

My javascript code is this.

`function ShowConfirmationMessage(xhr) {
    alert(xhr);}`

When I provide the OnSuccess method the code gets rendered like this.

```
<form action="/Review/SaveQualityScore" 
    method="post" 
    onclick="Sys.Mvc.AsyncForm.handleClick(this, new Sys.UI.DomEvent(event));" 
    onsubmit="Sys.Mvc.AsyncForm.handleSubmit(this, new Sys.UI.DomEvent(event), 
        { 
            insertionMode: Sys.Mvc.InsertionMode.replace, 
            httpMethod: &#39;POST&#39;, 
            updateTargetId: &#39;feedbackMsg&#39;, 
            onSuccess: Function.createDelegate(this, ShowConfirmationMessage) 
        });"
>
```

I'm guessing the Function.createDelegate is the problem. Because when I remove the OnSuccess property the function.CreateDelegate doesn't get rendered and everything works fine.

Anyways, I'm going crazy over here, any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Make sure the following scripts are both included:

- MicrosoftAjax.js
- MicrosoftMvcAjax.js

Comment: after probably 2 hours of trial and error, (and knowing exactly how to do this in straight jquery in about 5 minutes time) adding these stupid .js files is what made it work for me...

Answer (score 2):

Or better yet...if you're using MVC 3, be sure to include jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js. It'll render out your form tag cleaner.

Also, you might not want to include UpdateTargetId and OnSuccess together. I just spent 3 hours figuring out that if my controller is returning json, my onsuccess javascript callback function is never hit if I define UpdateTargetId in the Ajax.BeginForm.