# "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'Sys' is undefined" on Jquery dialog that renders "Log on partialview"

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-mvc-ajax

I am new in jquery, ajax and mvc.

I used Jquery dialog to show a log on partial view. when it is loaded and I click in its textbox or any other place on it, I get this error:

**"Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'Sys' is undefined"**

and show this script dynamic code for it:

```
function onclick(event) { Sys.Mvc.AsyncForm.handleClick(this, new Sys.UI.DomEvent(event)); }
```

I can't use these scripts for validate textboxes, because I have jquery accordion in my page and when I use these scripts, accordion doesn't work. Also above error shows again.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

What should I do to solve it?
How can I validate username and pass textboxes on dialog?
and ..
Can I use **@Html.ActionLink** in **@Ajax.beginform(){}**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this add  refrence on layout:-

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Arora I added it, but i got the new error :
**Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'AsyncForm': object is null or undefined** and shown the function above again.

Comment: I saw this link: "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347784/error-using-ajax-beginform-when-giving-a-callback-parameter-for-onsuccess-onfai" and added **MicrosoftMvcAjax.js** too. it solved my problem.

Comment: it should work <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>